# How to fetch value from another series or data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am looking for customized tooltip for specific series. in which I have tried multiple ways to make it working but can't get success.
I am getting data using AJAX in CodeIgniter PHP framework.

Currently I have multiple series. but I don't want to show test1 and test2 in graph. Please consider **X-axis value 10** to get exact idea about problem.

Test Series data :

```
[["01",0],["02",0],["03",0],["04",0],["05",0],["06",0],["07",0],["08",0],["09",0],["10",2068]
```

Test1 Series data :

```
[["01",0],["02",0],["03",0],["04",0],["05",0],["06",0],["07",0],["08",0],["09",0],["10",1510.2568],["11",0]]
```

Test2 Series data:

```
[["01",0],["02",0],["03",0],["04",0],["05",0],["06",0],["07",0],["08",0],["09",0],["10",4097],["11",0]]
```

For highcharts series test,test1,test2 my code looks like below
*response_data is a variable in which I am getting all above series in AJAX response.*

Response from my php page

```
{"test":[["01",0],["02",0],["03",0],["04",0],["05",0],["06",0],["07",0],["08",0],["09",0],["10",2068],["11",0],["12",0]],"test1":[["01",0],["02",0],["03",0],["04",0],["05",0],["06",0],["07",0],["08",0],["09",0],["10",1510.2568],["11",0],["12",0]],"test2":[["01",0],["02",0],["03",0],["04",0],["05",0],["06",0],["07",0],["08",0],["09",0],["10",4097],["11",0],["12",0]]}
```

Chart :

```
tooltip: {
           formatter: function() {
            if(this.series.name=='Test'){
              var current_point=this.point.name;
              var test1=response_data.test1.current_point;
              var test2=response_data.test2.current_point;
              return "Test :"+this.y+"<br/>Test1 : "+test1+"test2 :+test2;
            }else{
             return this.series.name+': <b>'+this.y+'</b>';
            }  
           }            
          },
          series: [
              {
                name: 'Test',
                type: 'column',
                data: response_data.test
              },
              {
               name: 'test1',
               data: response_data['test1'],
               visible: false
              },
              {
               name: 'test2',
               visible: false,
               data: response_data['test2']
               }
          ]
```

Output for point/X-axis 10:

```
Test:2068
Test1:1510.2568
Test2:4097
```

Comment: isn't this the output you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the data in arrays - you just have to reference them using the `this.x` value from inside the tooltip formatter:

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
    return '<b>Category: </b>'+this.key
          +'<br/><b>Test: </b>'+ this.y
          +'<br/><b>Test1: </b>'+ test1[this.x][1]
          +'<br/><b>Test2: </b>'+ test2[this.x][1];
  }
}
```

Fiddle example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/hh2g6urw/

Comment: @SebastianBochan Not sure what you mean - I am not seeing any errors?

Comment: @jlbriggs Thanks for your reply
Will you please help me some more ?
 i have added exact response but don't know how to fetch data from it
i have tried to response[test1][this.x][1] as well as response.test1.[this.x][1] both are not working